Megatron-llama TypeError: perform_nocolor_split(): incompatible function arguments
We are currently working with llama model in megatron (Specifically MEGATRON-LLAMA). We tried to run pretraining llama on single node with 8 GPUs using torchrun command, the training went perfectly fine but when we tried to run on multinode using slurm there was some
TypeError: perform_nocolor_split(): incompatible function arguments.

We are using PyTorch NGC Container (version: 24.01)
TP_SIZE=1
PP_SIZE=1
3: [rank3]: Traceback (most recent call last):
3: [rank3]:   File "/workspace/pretrain_llama.py", line 118, in <module>
3: [rank3]:     pretrain(train_valid_test_datasets_provider, model_provider,
3: [rank3]:   File "/workspace/megatron/training.py", line 90, in pretrain
3: [rank3]:     initialize_megatron(extra_args_provider=extra_args_provider,
3: [rank3]:   File "/workspace/megatron/initialize.py", line 76, in initialize_megatron
3: [rank3]:     finish_mpu_init()
3: [rank3]:   File "/workspace/megatron/initialize.py", line 56, in finish_mpu_init
3: [rank3]:     _initialize_distributed()
3: [rank3]:   File "/workspace/megatron/initialize.py", line 185, in _initialize_distributed
3: [rank3]:     mpu.initialize_model_parallel(args.tensor_model_parallel_size,
3: [rank3]:   File "/workspace/megatron/core/parallel_state.py", line 160, in initialize_model_parallel
3: [rank3]:     group = torch.distributed.new_group(list(ranks))
3: [rank3]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/distributed/c10d_logger.py", line 92, in wrapper
3: [rank3]:     func_return = func(*args, **kwargs)
3: [rank3]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/distributed/distributed_c10d.py", line 4092, in new_group
3: [rank3]:     return _new_group_with_tag(
3: [rank3]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/distributed/distributed_c10d.py", line 4172, in _new_group_with_tag
3: [rank3]:     pg, pg_store = _new_process_group_helper(
3: [rank3]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/distributed/distributed_c10d.py", line 1507, in _new_process_group_helper
3: [rank3]:     split_from.perform_nocolor_split(_get_default_group().bound_device_id)
3: [rank3]: TypeError: perform_nocolor_split(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
3: [rank3]:     1. (self: torch._C._distributed_c10d.ProcessGroupNCCL, arg0: torch.device) -> None
3: [rank3]: Invoked with: <torch.distributed.distributed_c10d.ProcessGroupNCCL object at 0x1551a5b06bb0>, None

We tried to run on single gpu without slurm and it ran perfectly fine but issue with slurm

Have you checked that the path set for NCCL is considering the correct version
